# Why won't my list align horizontally center

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm working on a basic nav bar project, and I've trying to get this list to align center. I've tried using `align-content` and `text-align`, but my bar is still positioned towards to the left.

Can you please show me how to center this list horizontally?

```
                  li1    li2      li3
```

(should be centered by css not spaces, of course)

Here is a [**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iguyf)

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300);
#bannercontent {
  font-family: 'Quicksand:300';
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.banner {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 560px;
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.links {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.links:hover {
  color: white;
}
.bannerlinks {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 12px;
  border-color: black;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bannercontent">
  <ul class="banner">
    <li class="bannerlinks"><a class="links" href="#">What We Do</a></li>
    <li class="bannerlinks"><a class="links" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li class="bannerlinks"><a class="links" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li class="bannerlinks"><a class="links" href="#">Wholesale</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: To clarify, do you want to center the list items relatively to the banner, or do you want to center the banner relatively to bannerconent?

Comment: I want the list items to be centered compared to the whole page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply give the .banner element margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;

```
.banner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need `margin: 0 auto;` on the child element.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b78dpn09/)

```
#bannercontent {
    font-family:'Quicksand:300';
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
.banner {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 560px;
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simply can done by balancing your margin .. as you given to right same do with giving left. here is the modified CSS

```
   @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300);

#bannercontent{
    font-family: 'Quicksand:300';
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
.banner{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 560px;
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.links{
    text-decoration: none;  
}
.links:hover{
    color: white;
    text-align:center;
}
.bannerlinks
{
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 12px;
    border-color: black;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the    /* the follwoing lines */ to .banner

margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;

Check the answer below:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300);

#bannercontent{


}



#bannercontent {
  font-family: 'Quicksand:300';
  font-size: 25px;
 
 
}
.banner {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 560px;
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  
   /* the follwoing lines */
    margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
}
.links {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.links:hover {
  color: white;
}
.bannerlinks {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 12px;
  border-color: black;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bannercontent">
  <ul class="banner">
    <li class="bannerlinks"><a class="links" href="#">What We Do</a></li>
    <li class="bannerlinks"><a class="links" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li class="bannerlinks"><a class="links" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li class="bannerlinks"><a class="links" href="#">Wholesale</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I just want to show complete running code no more . that was my purpose

Comment: great . as you see am just new here